# linking multiple tables together in mysql using aliases

Tags: mysql

I am sooo close but I can't figure this out. I have a database that holds staff members, their titles, the locations they are associated with (of which there can be several). I have made a SQL fiddle with some test information as well as part of my sql statement. The other part that I am missing is trying to get all the locations to show up with the corresponding staff members and their titles. I had this working before with another column in the staff table but I want to remove the title column and place it as it is in the fiddle. I have made aliases for contact1, contact2 and partner. But what I can't get to work is how to get their titles. I can only get one contact at a time. Any ideas guys?

[MySQl Fiddle is here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04326/2)

So can't really do a screen shot of the page but desired result would be that all locations show up with their associated contacts. 
so it would be something like:

- Location
- Address
- Phone number
- Contact 1
- Contact 2
- Partner

I have a php that formats the stuff I just need it to display that information. If the location doesn't have a contact 1 or contact 2 I have it making that disappear via the php. In the example there should be 6 locations showing, with all the contact information.

Comment: What is your desired result then? If possible, you could paste your intended result for a clearer picture.

Comment: oh sorry I knew there was something I was forgetting.

Comment: If so, you should use left join instead of inner join so that will display all 6 location regardless if the location do have contact1 or contact2 or partner. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04326/10

Comment: and not sure that works because the titles are what is messing up. I need the titles for Contact1, contact2 and partner to be associated with the contact. I can get all the information but the titles is what comes up wonky when I try to add that table to the sql statement

Comment: Its the same for the contact1/2/partner title. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04326/23 just use left join. i remove some of the fields in the fiddle for easier reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use left join to join for contact1/2/partner as in fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04326/23

Comment: awesome works perfectly thanks. I actually tried part of what you did with the separate left joins but it didn't like the way I did it. I must have switched them somewhere. Thank you so much.